# Moving different QGraphicsitems independent Qt GraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

So I'm trying to make an UML diagrams generator from c++ code, in Qt. The problem I have: when I draw a rectangle(diagram) I can move it all over the place, but when I generate several, I can only move the 1st one and the rest moving at the same time like they would be connected to the first rectangle.
I must mention that I'm new to Qt. I want to know how can I make to move every single item independent in order to figure a friendly class diagram.
One more thing to mention: the diagram shape is made from 3 combined rectangles(rec+rec1+rec2).
I'll show you the code:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H
#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include<QPainter>
#include<QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "mysquare.h"

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();


private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    //scene
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    MySquare *square;



};

#endif // DIALOG_H
##################################
```

mysquare.h: it's my GraphicsItem

```
#ifndef MYSQUARE_H
#define MYSQUARE_H
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QDebug>


class MySquare : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    MySquare();

    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    bool Pressed;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // MYSQUARE_H
```

MySquare.cpp

```
#include "mysquare.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

MySquare::MySquare()
{
    Pressed = false;
    setFlag(ItemIsMovable);
}

QRectF MySquare::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(50,90,130,220);
}

void MySquare::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    int a = 50, b = 90, c=130, d=220;
    QBrush brush(Qt::gray);
    QPen outlinePen(Qt::black);
    outlinePen.setWidth(2);

    //Let's say I want to draw 3 diagrams
    int k = 3;

    for(int i=1; i <=  k ; i++)     //k is the number of classes (diagrams)
    {
        QRectF rec(a,b,c,d);
        painter->fillRect(rec,brush);
        painter->drawRect(rec);
        painter->drawText(rec,Qt::AlignCenter,"Class name");

        QRectF rec1(a,b+20,c,100);
        painter->drawRect(rec1);
        painter->drawText(rec1,Qt::AlignVCenter,"Attributes");

        QRectF rec2(a,b+100,c,100);
        painter->drawRect(rec2);
        painter->drawText(rec2,Qt::AlignVCenter,"Methods");

        a = a + c + 25;
        b = b+50;
        if(i > 3)
        {
            if(i%4 == 0)    // Im doing this just because I cant move every diagram independently so I draw them at some distance
            {
                b = b+200;
                a = 50;
                c = 130;
            }
        }
    }


}

}

void MySquare::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    Pressed = true;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void MySquare::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    Pressed = false;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And in the dialog.cpp I have:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<QtGui>
#include<QPaintEvent>
#include<QGraphicsItem>

using namespace std;

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);



    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    square = new MySquare();
    scene ->addItem(square);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Do you want each rectangle inside `MySquare` to move independantly ?

Comment: Yes thats what I want. I'm not sure if I create those objects properly of there is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each independently movable item on the scene has to be a separate `QGraphicsItem` with the `ItemIsMovable` flag set.

You can also define dependencies between items so that a parent item drags its children items along, even if children can still move independently.

Comment: Could you please give me an example based on my  code? I'm new to Qt and it's kind of hard to catch up. I mean if I want to move independent  the next rectangle generated by the 'for(int i=1; i <=  k ; i++)   instruction, what do I have to change?

Comment: Use the paint function just for custom painting inside an item. Your loop creating the rectangles (items) should be done when you're creating new items (in your code that's the Dialog constructor).

Comment: Do I need MySquare class anymore?

Comment: Probably, but maybe with another name matching your UML representation, or something like "diagItem" if it's completely generic.

Comment: If I try with 'QGraphicsRectItem' instead of 'QRectF' it is possible to insert text like I do in 'QRectF' ?

Comment: Sure you can use `QGraphicsRectItem`, as long as you're creating items in the right place (i.e. not in the paint method).

Comment: So you told me "Your loop creating the rectangles (items) should be done when you're creating new items (in your code that's the Dialog constructor).". This means I have to copy the contains of the 'void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);' function in the DIalog constructor?

Comment: "This means I have to copy" => except you'd be creating items (QGraphicsRectItem) instead of QRectF